# Utilizar método update sem usar o edit, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma view q mostra a chave de acesso de um usuário, nela eu preciso apertar um button q vai atualizar a chave de acesso de forma aleatória, o update retorna para a view mas não modifica a chave. Como posso resolver isso?

Controller update:

```
public function update(User $api)
{
    //Cria chave e veriica a existencia no banco de dados
    $permitted_chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    $hash = substr(str_shuffle($permitted_chars), 0, 40);
    $validator = \Validator::make(['hash' => $hash], ['hash' => 'unique:users,api_access_Key']);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->randomId();
    }
    //fim

    $api->update([
        'api_access_key' => $hash,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('user.index');
}
```

controller index:

```
    public function index(User $model)
{ 
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $userIndex = DB::select("select * from users where id = '$id'");
    return view('apis.API', compact('userIndex'));

}
```

como eu chamo o método no botão:

```
<a href="{{ route('api.update', $api) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Nova chave') }}</a>
```

Comment: Tenta dar um `save` após o update:
`$api->update([
        'api_access_key' => $hash,
    ])->save();`

Comment: `return $this->randomId();` o que é isso? é um método? será que ele não está indo por ai ?

Comment: return $this->randomId():, caso a chave ja exista no banco de dados o script é executado novamente através deste return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito melhor que eu acho que utilizar o update e acho que a única é da seguinte forma:

```
public function update($id, Request $request){
         $dados = Model::find($id);

         $dados->dados = $request->dados;

         $dados->save();

         return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifique na model se o campo "api_access_key" esta no array `$fillable`

```
protected $fillable = [
    'api_access_key'
];
```

caso não tenha ou o array não exista, crie ele com as colunas que você quer alterar nos métodos create ou update

Comment: esse array ja existe.